# I would like to select all points where they are outside my polygon

Tags: sql, sql-server, gps

I would like to select all points where they are outside my polygon.

I have a column called `gps`, like `GEOGRAPHY`

This field contains latitude and longitude.

I declared the region of my polygon

```
DECLARE @thePolygon GEOGRAPHY
SET @thePolygon = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-78.50932668617881 45.024933647425115, -78.53403351361905 44.9898648154388, -78.48446979547693 44.97239241709962, -78.45973073293072 45.007441690111115, -78.50932668617881 45.024933647425115))', 4269);
```

now I wanted something like not in, ex.

```
[![select top 100 gps from MonitoramentosVTR
where gps not in GEOGRAPHY::STIntersection(@thePolygon)][1]][1]
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use STIntersects, eg:

```
select top 100 gps 
from MonitoramentosVTR
where gps.STIntersects(@thePolygon) = 0
order by ...
```

Comment: apparently ran but does not bring any information will the method i used to convert..
update MonitoringVTR set gps = geography :: Point (Lat, Long, 4326)

Comment: If you need more help, you'll have to add more information to your question.